# Очищение массива вне зоны видимости C++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память

Создал я программу вывода меню, ну и выполнения действий по пунктам меню:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int a[10] = {};
int k,n,l,nomer,min,summ;
char ch;
srand(time(NULL));
bool quit=true;
```

Тут через `cout` выводится меню:

```
while (quit) 
{   
cout<<'\n'<<"Введите номер пункта: ";
cin >> nomer;
    switch (nomer)
    {
      //Тут много case с 1 по 14
     case 13:
        {
            //Ругается на делиты массивов не знаю из-за чего
            //delete [] a;         
        }
        break;
```

Пытался сделать массив, a public он пишет ошибку: типа нет аргумента, может я не правильно писал.

Вообщем как правильно удалить массив?

У меня удаляется только если в `case` одном и том же удаляет, а вне `case` массив не видит программа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Удаление через

```
delete [] a;
```

допустимо только для массива, выделенного через `new []`:

```
int * a = new int[N];
```

Ваш массив локальный, в стеке, уничтожится сам при выходе из `main()`.

Comment: ну это да а мне надо что бы он удалялся только при вызове 13 case, вот как это сделать?

Comment: @ТимурБердиев вместо `int a[10] = {};` написать `int * a = new int[10];` ??? Ну как в ответе вам написали.

Comment: Вам скорее **не надо** писать `delete`. Зачем вы его хотите удалять? Чем он вам мешает?

Comment: @Harry пункт в меню 13 должен очищать все массивы в программе. Именно 13 пункт, а не в конце case писать delete[] a

Comment: Еще раз и медленно. Нигде, совсем нигде! Ни в 13 пункте, ни в каком ином, вообще нигде не надо писать `delete[]` для массива, созданного в стеке как локальная переменная. Вообще!